# Difference in file manipulation between Python 2.7 and 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, io, compatibility

So I am working on a program that encrypts files with a transpositional cypher. I am used to Python 2.7 and I tried it on a file. But it seems that 2.7 file.read() function does very different things than Python 3.5's. For future reference, what is the exact difference in those functions or maybe it's something to do with the file object itself?

There is probably some documentation on it but I have no idea how to efficiently find stuff in there :/

For the curious here is the code:

```
import transposition1, os, sys

def fileEncrypt(name, key):
    file = open(name, "r+")
    encryptedFileName = name + "Encrypted.txt"
    if os.path.exists(encryptedFileName):
        print('This will overwrite the file %s. (C)ontinue or (Q)uit?' % (encryptedFileName))
        response = input('> ')
        if not response.lower().startswith('c'):
            sys.exit()
        else:
            encryptedFile = open(encryptedFileName, "w+")
    else:
        encryptedFile = open(encryptedFileName, "w+")

    contents = file.read()
    cyphertext = transposition1.encode(contents, key)
    encryptedFile.write(cyphertext)

    encryptedFile.close()
    file.close()


def fileDecrypt(name, key):
    file = open(name, "r+")
    decryptedFileName = name + "Decrypted.txt"
    if os.path.exists(decryptedFileName):
        print('This will overwrite the file %s. (C)ontinue or (Q)uit?' % (decryptedFileName))
        response = input('> ')
        if not response.lower().startswith('c'):
            sys.exit()
        else:
            decryptedFile = open(decryptedFileName, "w+")
    else:
        decryptedFile = open(decryptedFileName, "w+")

    cyphertext = file.read()
    plaintext = transposition1.decode(cyphertext, key)
    decryptedFile.write(plaintext)

    decryptedFile.close()
    file.close()



def main():
    decision = input("What do you want to do? (encrypt/decrypt)\n")

    if decision == "encrypt":
        name = input("What is the name of the .txt file?\n") + ".txt"
        if not os.path.exists(name):
            print('The file %s does not exist. Quitting...' % (name))
            sys.exit()

        key = input("What key do you want to use? (integer)\n")
        try:
            key = int(key)
        except ValueError:
            print("You dumb.")

        fileEncrypt(name, key)
        print("Encryption finished.")

    if decision == "decrypt":
        name = input("What is the name of the .txt file?\n") + ".txt"
        if not os.path.exists(name):
            print('The file %s does not exist. Quitting...' % (name))
            sys.exit()

        key = input("What key do you want to use? (integer)\n")
        try:
            key = int(key)
        except ValueError:
            print("You dumb.")

        fileDecrypt(name, key)
        print("Decryption finished.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `r` and `w` in python2 write a binary type (non-unicode) whereas in python3 it is a text type.  To make them the same, prefer `import io; io.open`.  To ensure the python2 behaviour in both places, use `rb` and `wb`.

Comment: what if my intention is to store it as text? i need it in readable form and if the file is open in wb it will write stuff in binary right?

Comment: Your code as written is writing in binary mode in python2.  If you want to always write via the text type (`unicode` in  PY2 and `str` in PY3), use `io.open` with `w` and `r`.